# mod-rewrite with a number in the file name not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I seem to be having a hard time pattern matching something that should be simple :/

I want to dynamically match css files using a simple version numbering system, like so:

**[url]/css/name-of-file.001.css** will redirect to **[url]/css/name-of-file.css**

This works fine using the following htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule ^css/(.+).([0-9]+).css$ /css/$1.css [L]
```

BUT...

...it fails completely when I try to get to *ie6.css* (I know ie6 is a billion years old but some of us still have to support it... like it or not).

It seems to be an issue with the number 6 in the filename, but as far as I'm aware *"(.+)"* means *"any character or number, one or more times"*

What gives? Any help is much appreciated! I've tried every combination I can come up with...

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be:

```
RewriteRule ^css/(.+)\.([0-9]+)\.css$ /css/$1.css [L]
```

Note that you'll have to escape the `.` if it appears in pattern. Otherwise it stands for *any character*

Comment: Works for: _menu.css_, _menu.001.css_, _ie6.css_ but NOT _ie6.001.css_